# .NET target framework compatibility and the compiler - on .NET 4.5 or higher

Tags: c#, .net, compilation

I'm fairly experienced in .NET development but today I was forced to wrap my head around something I'd never thought about before:

**How do the installed .NET Framework, the .NET Framework target in Visual Studio and the C# compiler work together?**

Concrete example: The `System.dll` contains the enum `System.Net.SecurityProtocolType`. On .NET 4.5 this enum contains the members `SSl3` , `Tls`, `Tls11`, and `Tls12`. With .NET 4.7, the member `SystemDefault` was added.

So, targeting .NET 4.7.x, this code compiles fine:

```
var p = SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault;
```

However, when I target .NET 4.5.x, this code does not compile (as one would expect).

What puzzles me here is why this works considering that .NET 4.7 is an **in-place update** to .NET 4.5 (i.e. when installing .NET 4.7, the `System.dll` of .NET 4.5 is replaced with the one of .NET 4.7).

How does the compiler know that I can't use `SystemDefault` on .NET 4.5 but can use it on 4.7? Is this done via some kind of API file known to the compiler?

> **Side fact:** When I target .NET 4.5 and have .NET 4.7 installed, a call to `Enum.GetValues(typeof(SecurityProtocolType)` will give me `SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault`. So I'm fairly certain that my .NET 4.5 application uses the .NET 4.7 `System.dll`.

Comment: Your machine has different sets of reference assemblies, the C# compiler uses the set that matches the target you selected.  Find them back in the c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies directory.  Intention is to allow you to build a program that runs on another machine with an older version of .NET.  Or a completely different framework version, as used in Silverlight, UWP and .NETCore targets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How does the compiler know that I can't use SystemDefault on .NET 4.5 but can use it on 4.7? Is this done via some kind of API file known to the compiler?

Yes, I'd expect it to be done via the *reference assemblies*. A reference assembly is an assembly which includes just the accessible API definitions, effectively.

On my Windows machine, these are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework`

Answer (score 4):

When you specify a target of .NET Framework 4.5, you are specifying the *interface surface* of that API. The compiler uses this exact version to determine what types are available.

When .NET Framework 4.7 runtime exists on the target machine, the types are forwarded from 4.5 to 4.7. But this is *just the runtime behavior*. It doesn't change the fact the target was .NET Framework 4.5 when the application was compiled. Keep in mind when the assembly is deployed on the target machine, it is already compiled to *intermediate language*. The compiler is not involved at all during runtime and therefore cannot dynamically change the target framework.

As for your side fact, that is the *runtime behavior* of Reflection that works that way because the runtime framework it is using is 4.7.

Comment: Can you please explain me a little bit more when build is targeted at .net 4.5 and .net 4.7 is exists the runtime will use .net 4.7? So the highest version of .net framework will be used at runtime? correct me if I am wrong, thanks

Comment: Essentially, when any version of .NET Framework Runtime 4.0+ is installed on a machine, it will [*replace* the previous version and re-target it to use the latest version that is installed](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx). This is different behavior than most other .NET Framework Runtime installs, which can be run side-by-side.